# Declare a class/struct

Tags: c++

For example, i have a struct and I'm using static function of class to initialize its members. how can i tell the complier that the class exists but it is defined after the structure S?

```
struct S
{
    S()
    {
        x = C::GetX(); //static functions, GetX() and GetY()
        y = C::GetY();
    }

int x; int y;
};

class C
{
 /.... /
}
```

**Edit:** I will also be using  `struct S` in `class C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `C` first.

Without more context, it's hard to answer in more depth.

```
struct S;

class C
{
 /.... /
};

struct S
{
    S()
    {
        x = C::GetX(); //static functions, GetX() and GetY()
        y = C::GetY();
    }

int x; int y;
};
```

Or, you might need to define `S::S` outside the `class S` block.

```
struct S
{
    S();

int x; int y;
};

class C
{
 /.... /
};

S::S()
{
    x = C::GetX(); //static functions, GetX() and GetY()
    y = C::GetY();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using member functions of class `C` in the definition of `S`, you'll need to declare `C` *before* `S`.